# Python: Definitions made in external shell get a bad `.__module__` attribute

Tags: python, shell, module, wxpython, read-eval-print-loop

I am making a wxPython app which supplies a shell for the user to use. (This is [`wx.lib.shell.PyShell`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.shell.PyShell-class.html), the shell that ships with wxPython.)

Problem is, definitions made in this shell have a bad `.__module__` attribute. For example:

```
>>> def f(): 0
... 
>>> f.__module__
>>> f.__module__ is None
True
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
...     
>>> 
>>> A.__module__
'__builtin__'
```

I think the `.__module__` attribute for both these objects should be `__main__`. Not sure. But it definitely shouldn't be either `None` or `__builtin__`.

How can I make the shell give a good `.__module__` attribute to these functions and classes?

Comment: I think they both should be `None`.

Comment: What makes you think the shell is giving the objects the attribute with this value?

Comment: What is the value of `__name__` in your `wx`-based shell? It's `'__main__'` in the standard Python shell. Perhaps you can set that to what you want in your shell's initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happened is because I was using a custom locals dict, and neglected to put a meaningful `'__name__'` in it. Once you put a `'__name__'` item in the locals dict you give to PyShell, its value will be used to set the `.__module__` attribute for functions and classes defined in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

In IDLE and in the wxPython Demo's PyShell demo, I get the following:

```
>>> def f(): 0

>>> f.__module__
'__main__'
>>> f.__module__ is None
False
>>> class A(object):
        pass

>>> A.__module__
'__main__'
```

It seems to work correctly to me. I'm not sure what you're doing on your machine. I am using Python 2.5, wxPython 2.8.10.1 on Windows XP.